# How to merge list of strings into list of lists?

Tags: python, string, list, nested, nested-lists

I have a list like this :

`list_1 = ['2a', '3b', '2c', '2d', ... ]`

and an another list like this :

`list_2 = [[], [], [], ['3a'], ['3b']... ]`

These two lists have the same size. I want to merge them to obtain a third one:

`list_3 = [['2a'], ['3b'], ['2c','3a'], ['2d','3b']...]`

I tried to use dataFrames to merge, I tried some differents loops but all I got is wrong. I tried some answers of similars questions but nothing I got with them is what I expect.

This is some examples I tried :

```
list_3 = list(product(list_1, list_2))
```

```
for i in list_2:
     for j in list_2:
         list_3 = list.append(str(i) + str(j))

list_3 =  [[str(list_1[x]) + str(x)] for x in list1,list_2]
```

The issues I get are :

```py
list_3 = [['2a', '3b', '2c', '2d'...], [],[]....]
```

```
list_3 = [('2a', []), ('3b',[]), ('2c',['3a']), ...]
```

Have you any solutions ? If the answer already exists please link it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ensure that both lists have the same length, then use their index to append to the new list. Simple solution using only `list[index]` and list comprehension:

```
list_1 = ['2a', '3b', '2c', '2d']
list_2 = [ [], [], ['3a'], ['3b'] ]

if len(list_1) == len(list_2):
    new_list = [[list_1[i]] + list_2[i] for i in range(len(list_1))]
print(new_list)
```

Output

```
[['2a'], ['3b'], ['2c', '3a'], ['2d', '3b']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just `zip` the lists and merge each `tuple(str, list)` using `+` after changing the string to a `list`

```
list_3 = [[x] + z for x, z in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```

An alternative to `zip` is to iterate over the lists using `enumerate`

```
list_3 = [[x] + list_2[i] for i, x in enumerate(list_1)]
```

Output

```
print(list_3) # [['2a'], ['3b'], ['2c', '3a'], ['2d', '3b']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to pair stuff, don't double-loop or product anything

Use `zip` to iterate on both then build the merge

```
list_1 = ['2a', '3b', '2c', '2d']
list_2 = [[], [], ['3a'], ['3b']]

result = []
for value1, sublist2 in zip(list_1, list_2):
    result.append([value1] + sublist2)

print(result)
# [['2a'], ['3b'], ['2c', '3a'], ['2d', '3b']]
```